# How to make DateTimeFormatter output 3 character months in French

Tags: java

I'm working on internationalizing an existing system to support French. I'd like months to be shown using 3 character abbreviations to be consistent with the English version. Unfortunately, and surprisingly MMM outputs a mixture of 3 and 4 character strings, in lowercase with full stops.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);
for (Month month : Month.values()) {
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, month, 1, 23, 59);
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uu").format(date));
}
```

Output

```
01 janv. 20
01 févr. 20
01 mars 20
01 avr. 20
01 mai 20
01 juin 20
01 juil. 20
01 août 20
01 sept. 20
01 oct. 20
01 nov. 20
01 déc. 20
```

After looking at the Javadoc it appears MMM outputting 3 character month strings in English is coincidence not design. [TextStyle.SHORT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html#SHORT) states

> Short text, typically an abbreviation. For example, day-of-week Monday
>   might output "Mon".

I'd prefer to use the existing i18n facilities in Java without having to introduce my own strings via properties files etc.

The best I've managed is the following, somewhat hacky code. Surely there must be an easier way? 
Is there any API to redefine the months programmatically so "MMM" works as I want "out of the box"?

```
for (Month month : Month.values()) {
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, month, 1, 23, 59);

    String original = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd 'MMM' uu").format(date);
    String monthStr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(date);
    if (monthStr.length() > 3) {
        monthStr = monthStr.substring(0, 3);
    }
    monthStr = monthStr.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + monthStr.substring(1);
    System.out.println(original.replace("MMM", monthStr));
}
```

Output

```
01 Jan 20
01 Fév 20
01 Mar 20
01 Avr 20
01 Mai 20
01 Jui 20
01 Jui 20
01 Aoû 20
01 Sep 20
01 Oct 20
01 Nov 20
01 Déc 20
```

Comment: It's meant to convert to the form the French are used to, not the way you think it should look. If you want "Butchered French" instead of I18N, then you'll need to implement it yourself. In case you don't see it, it looks really weird. I'm not native French, but I've lived in France and for example `Aoû` looks just ridiculous (not to mention that you can't distinguish between juin and juillet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings used in the Java time API are not configurable.

The best I could come up with was to escape the MMM and then replace it with either the "out of the box" value for English, or a custom value for French.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
    for (Month month : Month.values()) {
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, month, 1, 23, 59);
        String original = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd 'MMM' uu").format(date);
        System.out.println(original.replace("MMM", getMonth(date.getMonth())));
    }
}

private static String getMonth(Month month) {
    if (Locale.FRENCH.getLanguage().equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage())) {
        return new String[] { "Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aoû", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov",
                "Déc" }[month.ordinal()];
    } else {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(month);
    }
}
```